# How to import a random forest model from R into Android Studio?

Tags: r, android-studio, machine-learning, random-forest, pmml

So I have trained a random forest model in R which I have converted into a pmml file. But how do you import the pmml file into Android Studio and use it for predictions? I have a hard time finding examples of this online. The model is very simple and I only have 4 features which are used to classify the input data as "A","B" or "C". So I want to, given these 4 features, be able to input that into my trained model and get an output in the app. Is there some interface that I can import and use?

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have a pmml you may better checkout [this](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-android) library. It's a PMML evaluator for Android. You could be able to import your pmml for inferences with it. Hope this would be useful. 
Note: I haven't tried this particular library myself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the installation file it say that I should go to the project root and enter "mvn clean install". How do I do that? Like in windows cmd or what?

Comment: Yes, first make sure you have maven installed in your system https://maven.apache.org/install.html then you have to run "mvn clean install" on cmd from project root.

Comment: And project root, is that my Android Studio root directory?  Or where should I install it? Thank you for the help